Using OpenAI API for answering questions about csv file
I'm starting with OpenAI API and experimenting with langchain. I have a .csv file with approximately 1000 rows and 85 columns with string values. I found some beginner article that I followed and have a colab notebook with the following code:
txt_file_path = '/content/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/preprocessed_data_10.csv'

with open(txt_file_path, 'r', encoding="utf-8") as file:
  data = file.read()

txt_file_path = '/content/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/preprocessed_data_10.csv'
loader = TextLoader(file_path=txt_file_path, encoding="utf-8")
data = loader.load()

text_splitter = CharacterTextSplitter(chunk_size=1000, chunk_overlap=200)
data = text_splitter.split_documents(data)

embeddings = OpenAIEmbeddings()

vectorstore = FAISS.from_documents(data, embedding=embeddings)


llm = ChatOpenAI(temperature=0.7, model_name="gpt-4")
memory = ConversationBufferMemory(memory_key='chat_history', return_messages=True)

conversation_chain = ConversationalRetrievalChain.from_llm(
    llm=llm,
    chain_type="stuff",
    retriever=vectorstore.as_retriever(),
    memory=memory
)

query = "question"
result = conversation_chain({"question": query})
answer = result["answer"]
answer

The errors I got were:
Error code: 429 - {'error': {'message': 'Request too large for gpt-4 in organization org-xxx on tokens per min (TPM): Limit 10000, Requested 139816.

and
BadRequestError: Error code: 400 - {'error': {'message': "This model's maximum context length is 8192 tokens. However, your messages resulted in 32045 tokens.

I tried to figure out how big csv file I can feed it with and reduced the file for 10 rows and 53 columns.
What are possible workarounds so I can search on entire csv file?
Any help would be much appreciated.
Thanks.

have you tried creating an index using standard libraries, and then ask the question to the LLM ?

Yeah I'm thinking of creating a list with ids and then based on id search the row in csv file. Is that what you mean?

It is not usual to pass large csv to LLMs. Alternatively you can generate proper code from LLM and then execute with exec() function. In this way it will execute the code on your PC and it will solve the token limit.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
